# MySQLi not returning results from a JOIN prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli

```
function fullJoinTest()
{
    $con = ModelBase::getConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT airline, airport
            FROM airlines
            LEFT JOIN airports on airlines.icao_code = airports.icao_code";
    $query = $con->prepare($sql) or die("Error preparing sql in Search (test) ");

    $query->execute() or die("Error executing query in Search (test) ");

    error_log($query->num_rows);
}
```

Now it keeps returning `0` for the number of rows it's returning. When I plug that same query into phpMyAdmin it returns the expected result set.

Does MySQLi play nice with JOINs? Is there another way to go around this? Eventually it will have a lot more joins and some `WHERE` clauses. I would like to keep using prepared statements.

Comment: Are you using the same credentials to connect to the database from PHP as with phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Yes, they are identical.

Comment: if you enable query tracing in the DB, do you see both the 0-row query coming from php as well as the one from phpmyadmin?

Comment: How do I enable query tracing? The only db access I have is through phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not yet read the rows, so it doesn't know how many were produced.
call $query->store_result(); to buffer the rows into memory.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php